# Systemd limit StandardOutput file size

Tags: systemd, logs, raspberry-pi, stdout

I created a systemd service on my Pi 4 that writes std output to a file using `StandardOutput=file:/file/location/file.log`. Is there a way to limit the file size of the log file to prevent it from taking up too much space?

Comment: I don't think there is in this constellation. What would you like to happen when the maximum size is reached? Service gets killed? New file gets started, and old file renamed, old-old files get deleted?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Best case, I would like the oldest logs to be removed and the newest ones added to the log file. At the very minimum I would like the service to stop writing to that file.

Comment: ah removing the beginning of a file is not something you can "easily" implement on a UNIXoid system (or in fact, any system I'm aware of), that would always require a complete re-writing of the file. What you could do is use logrotate!

Comment: btw, almost certain you either want `append:` or `truncate:`, not `file:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most forward way of dealing with this is using the `logrotate` program (probably already installed, and automatically running periodically, e.g. once a day).

For that to work, you'd add a file `yourservice.conf` in the `/etc/logrotate.d` directory (check that `/etc/logrotate.conf` contains `include /etc/logrotate.d`). This makes a new file every (a little more than) 10 MB, and keeps the most recent 5:

```
   /file/location/file.log {
       rotate 5
       size 10M
       postrotate
           systemctl restart yourservice.service
       endscript
   }
```

If the frequency of `logrotate.timer` is too low (default: daily), i.e. if your program writes more than `size` in a single day, you will have to modify the timer interval.

Note that you would be well-advised to not even start writing high-rate logs you don't need on a raspberry pi, if /file/location/file.log is on an SD card: These tend to wear off relatively quickly. Worn-out flash storage is the nr 1 reason for data loss and hardware-caused failure in RPis and similar SBCs.